# CanvasJS, issues with setting a user input Title for chart

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I am currently facing an issue with creating a user input title for a canvasJS chart. I am currently running through the tutorial over at canvasJS, and I thought it would make a neat small project to create a user input oriented pie chart.

The current issue I am facing is trying to get the text inputted from HTML to show up correctly.

[JSFiddle]https://jsfiddle.net/n3n0pssc/

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
               title:{
document.getElementById("chartTitle").setAttribute("text")
}`
```

I understand that the title must be set by tying it together with the addDataPointsAndRender function, but I am confused as canvasJS only displays set text by title: {text : "title"} and I am trying to figure out how it would go together by fetching input text.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the user inputs to the chart by either using chart options or by using the set() methods of the CanvasJS API.

I have modified your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suyashsingh/m8c04xdt/), and its working now.

```
function addDataPointsAndRender(){
    chart.options.title.text =document.getElementById("chartTitle").value;
    chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.push({ 
        y: parseFloat(document.getElementById("yValue1").value),
        indexLabel: document.getElementById("indexLabel1").value
    });
    chart.render();
}
```

Also have a look at :

1. [Tutorial on Rendering chart from user Input](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/render-chart-by-accepting-datapoints-from-user-input/)
2. [Updating Chart Options](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/updating-chart-options/)
3. [CanvasJS Methods & Properties Documentation](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/)

Comment: Thank you so much Suyash! The set() method was something I wasn't fully knowledgeable about and the information you linked helped me resolve a lot of those issues.

Thanks!